# How to create methods at runtime with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to declare / create 20 methods dynamically with Objective-C. Those methods will be added to action listeners. The methods will have almost the same implementation, there will be only a few differences. But I don't wanna have to write these methods 20 times. I know how to store blocks of methods into an array, however I am having trouble passing those methods to action listeners. That is what I have:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new];
[arr addObject:^(){NSLog(@"my block");}];
id (^ myblock)() = [arr objectAtIndex:0];

sel_registerName("myblock");

[numPad addTarget:self action:@selector(myblock) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

notice that the action parameters expects a selector, but I got an error because 'myblock' inside the @selector won't return anything, as 'myblock' has not been declared yet.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Is really necessary to you to create those methods at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really, *really* need to create a target/action target at runtime, the simplest solution is to use an `NSBlockOperation`. E.g.

```
NSMutableArray *blockOperations = [NSMutableArray new];
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

    NSBlockOperation *blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"I am listener %d", i);
    }];

    [blockOperations addObject:blockOperation];
    [numPad addTarget:blockOperation action:@selector(start) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Though if your target is called `numPad`, what you probably want to do is wire all the individual buttons into *the same* target and just give them a tag that represents their value. E.g.

```
- (void)numPadButtonAction:(UIView *)sender {
    NSLog(@"user pressed button with tag %@", @(sender.tag));
}
```

Comment: Hey Tommy yeah, I had already figured this out. I did exactly what you suggested. Thanks !